# Append multiple items to a list on a for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested python for loop and need to append 2 times a value, is the code below PEP8 valid? Or there is a better pythonic way to to write the function?

```
def function():
    empty_list = []
    my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    for letter_1 in my_list: 
        for letter_2 in my_list:
            empty_list.append(letter_1)
            empty_list.append(letter_2)
    return empty_list
```

Comment: what is the output you expect ?

Comment: " is the code below PEP8 valid?" - yes. "is there a better pythonic way to to write the function?" - there is.

Comment: It can probably be done better using something from `itertools`

Comment: Does the order of elements in your resulting list matter?

Comment: `return list(chain.from_iterable(product(my_list, repeat=2))`

Comment: I would use `itertools` as @Barmar suggests as well, but even without that, I would use `extend()` rather than call `append()` twice.. `empty_list.extend((letter_1, letter_2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right and PEP8 compliant. I would remove the `my_list` from the function block and make it a function's parameter. I would suggest using `list.extend()` to perform the operation you need in one line. In order to make it a bit more Pythonic I would add **typing hints** and the function's **docstring**. The code would look like this:

```py
from typing import List

def function(my_list: List) -> List:
    """Function's docstring.

    Args:
        my_list (List): List of characters.

    Returns:
        List: Processed list of characters.
    """
    empty_list = []
    for a in my_list:
        for b in my_list:
            empty_list.extend((a, b))
    return empty_list
```

I don't know which IDE you use, but on Visual Studio Code you can download some extensions to generate docstrings automatically from your function's/classes' signature and typing hints. And also, there's extensions to automatically lint Python code to be PEP8 compliant.

I would also add a small test to make sure my function works as expected. Something like this:

```
assert function(['a', 'b', 'c']) == ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c',
                                     'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your desired output is:

**Desired output:**

```
['a','a','a','b','a','c',  # letter_1, with loop of letter_2
 'b','a','b','b','b','c',  # letter_2, with loop of letter_2
 'c','a','c','b','c','c']  # letter_3, with loop of letter_2
```

**An alternative** (more "pythonic"?) way to write your function is to use the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) library and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def alt_function(my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']):
    iterable = chain.from_iterable([a+b for a, b in product(my_list, repeat=2)])
    return list(iterable)
    
alt_function()
```

**Output**

```
['a','a','a','b','a','c',
 'b','a','b','b','b','c',
 'c','a','c','b','c','c']
```